# Submitting a form in java to a webpage using post method

Tags: java, forms, post, html

I'm wondering how to submit a form from an xml file to a specific webpage using post method in java.

**This is My XML file:**

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.Frag2"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="top">

        <!-- form name-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/app_form_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

      <!-- form phone -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/app_form_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:hint="Phone Number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



        <!-- form Email -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/app_form_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- form Message-->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/app_form_message"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:hint="Message"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
      
      <!--form action button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Submit"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Let's say that the webpage that I want to submit the form to is http://www.sidonianews.net/test/_app_form.php

Comment: Sorry, you take data from your app android with field and you would send the data with HTTP post protocol to a Web App created with java.net/servlet?

Comment: exactly that what i want